# How do I pass an array parameter to an object from a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, maze

I need to pass a `String[][]` parameter from a class that I made, for example:

```
public class Maze {

    String maze[][];
    int rows;
    int columns;
    int xStart;
    int yStart;

    public Maze(String xMaze[][], int xRows, int xColumns, int xxStart, int xyStart) {     
        maze = xMaze;
        rows = xRows;
        columns = xColumns;
        xStart = xxStart;
        yStart = xyStart;
    }
```

I need to call the `String maze[][]` in my main class but the only way I know to do so is by calling it null. What's a way I can initialize it by calling it as an object? My example of the null is below.

```
static Maze maze = new Maze(null,0,0,0,0);
```

Is there a way to call the `String[][]` rather than just a null? Seems like such a simple question yet I can't find the answer.

Comment: create the instance of String array and pass ?

Comment: I want to call the maze array from the maze class with the object posted at the bottom, but I cant find a way to do it other than null.

Comment: Some terminology: you don't "call a parameter", instead you "pass a value to a parameter"

Comment: If you want the `Maze` to manage and build is own array, why do you have the parameter `String[][] xMaze` in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Maze maze = new Maze(new String[2][2],0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the `Maze` constructor build the array, remove the array parameter and use the row/column values received :

```
public Maze(int xRows, int xColumns, int xxStart, int xyStart) {     
    maze = new String[xRows][xColumns];
    rows = xRows;
    columns = xColumns;
    xStart = xxStart;
    yStart = xyStart;
}
```

You don't need to input the array AND the array size in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance of `String` array and pass it

```
String[][] ar = new String[2][3]; // initialize with appropriate size
Maze maze = new Maze(ar,0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot.